# exist a javascript callback cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Look this code guys:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#<?=$delete_uid?>").click(function() {
    var id = $("#<?=$grid_uid?>").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    alert(id);
    if(id == null) {
        $.jGrowl("No selected Item");
        return;
    }

    confirm('Caution','Delete current selected item?', function(result) {
        if(result==true) {
            alert(id);
            url = "<?=ADMIN_URL?>/account/delete/id/" + id;
            execURL(url, function(result) {
                if (result==true) {
                    $.jGrowl("Item removed!!");
                    $("#<?=$grid_uid?>").trigger("reloadGrid");
                } else
                    $.jGrowl("Remove failure!!");
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

obs: alert is for debugging purpose only.

In first pass id comes from jqgrid its write an everything its ok but, on second time id only in confirm function callback maintains the first value.

Please help, lost 3 hours on this!

Comment: That isn't very clear... can you explain? What does the `alert` show? What do you expect?

Comment: allert if for debug purpose only this show current selected row id of my jqgrid. in second call of this rotine alert is correct two but on mount of url variable de id mantain the last id selected!!

Comment: The question has many grammar and spelling errors and is very difficult for someone to understand. Try to use a spell checker or ask a friend to write the question for you.

Comment: you spend 3 hours working on the problem, but apparently about 23 seconds formulating a decent question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use different syntax for 'confirm' function. Do not pass function to it, but use its return value as result:

```
 if(confirm('Caution','Delete current selected item?')){
            alert(id);
            url = "<?=ADMIN_URL?>/account/delete/id/" + id;
            execURL(url, function(result) {
                if (result==true) {
                    $.jGrowl("Item removed!!");
                    $("#<?=$grid_uid?>").trigger("reloadGrid");
                } else
                    $.jGrowl("Remove failure!!");
            });
 };
```

This should help.